# Can I use our sponsors as other compnay logos?

Tags: internet

I have a blog related to web designing.

I make money via affiliate marketing.

Can I use our sponsors as other company ( the companies which I used to make money via affiliate marketing)  logos?

Is it legal?

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you use it.

The issue is ***marketplace confusion***.

To be ***fair use*** (i.e., not infringement), you must use the logo in a way that a typical consumer will not be confused into thinking your web site *owns* the logo (i.e., is *your* brand or *mark*) but, instead, that you are referring to the *actual* mark owner, who is not you.

[To learn more, I recommend you read this article](http://www.bthinkforward.com/media-logos/). There, it says:

http://www.bthinkforward.com/media-logos/

> One fundamental principle to understand is that trademarks are not designed to protect companies. Trademarks are designed to protect customers from confusion.